# Wireless doesn't work ( hp635 notebook pc ) (ubuntu 12.04 )

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I installed ubuntu 12.04 most everything is working except the wireless. I have tried many solutions but none of them worked.

The original issue before complicating it by installing several drivers for different devices is `rfkill list all` shows a `hardblock`.

Can anyone help resolve this issue?

As requested:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script
```

Output (wireless-info.txt):

http://pastebin.com/5CmCpCu0

(Some Changes)

http://pastebin.com/awK8wniD

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5CmCpCu0

Comment: You have several drivers loaded, are you using any wifi devices besides your internal?

Comment: Actually I do not know, so help me to know !!

I am a beginner in linux !!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/awK8wniD 

i saw that and i think there is change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run the following commands in the terminal by copying and pasting for accuracy:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

reboot, then post a new file so we can see what other drivers are still loaded.

EDIT: 
Please copy and paste the following code:

```
echo "blacklist bcma b43 ssb 8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot

Edit:

Post the contents of:

```
cat /etc/modules
```

Edit:
Please run the following command in the terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

a small window will open type in your user password and the `/etc/modules` file will open, then remove:

```
8192cu and b43
```

from the file then save and close gedit then reboot.

EDIT:
Please run the following command in the terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

a small window will open type in your user password a file will open, then remove:

```
hp-wmi
```

both instances of it from the file then save and close gedit then reboot.

Now hopefully your wifi button will turn wifi on and off.

EDIT:
Run this command

```
echo "blacklist hp-wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then reset your bios, you need to be careful doing this:

1.
Turn on or restart the computer, and then press 
esc
while the “Press the ESC key for Startup Menu”
message is displayed at the bottom of the screen.

2.
Press f10 to enter Setup Utility.

3.
Use the arrow keys to select Exit > Load Setup Defaults.

4.
Follow the on-screen instructions.

5.
To save your changes and exit, press 
f10, and then follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: Can you rewrite the question in something understandable?